# Annotating C/C++ code

Tags: c++, c, annotations

Recently I got a grasp of Microsoft's [Standard Annotation Language (SAL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182032.aspx) for annotating C/C++ source codes. This feature can be very helpful for debugging and during development but unfortunately it is not a portable cross-platform library. Is there any standard or open-source tool for annotating C/C++ codes? Is there a similar feature available in **gcc**?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The closest that I'm aware is [GCC's attributes](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Attribute-Syntax.html), but other compilers don't support the syntax.  GCC attribute syntax does not support as many annotations as SAL, but you may find some of the annotations useful.

Alternatively, if you're using templates, you may want to check out [Boost Static Assert](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_staticassert.html), which most compilers support.

Also note that [CLANG supports more annotations than GCC](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/annotations.html), and using CLANG's static analyzer may be closer to what you're wanting.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. These tools are good and can be very helpful.By the way, these tools are all compiler-specific. Are you aware of any tool that can be used with different compilers and on different platforms?

Comment: No, sadly I'm not aware of anything that works across compilers.  I've used C++ macros for some of the annotations I've needed in the past.  Something like this [compiler_specific.h](http://src.chromium.org/chrome/trunk/src/base/compiler_specific.h) header, except add support for the additional SAL like annotations.

Comment: An additional thought - possibly you only need the SAL extensions to work on MSVC, and under other compilers you basically noop the annotations.  You can only run your static analyzer on the Windows platform, but at least it'll still compile on other platforms using other compilers.  I do this already for other reasons - gcc is more compliant than msvc, so I generally compile on gcc to make sure I'm writing standard code, but msvc has better error messages, especially with regard to template errors, and so I use msvc when I'm hitting a compiler error I can't crack.

Comment: This a good technique. Thanks.

Comment: I published [a header](https://github.com/nemequ/salieri) to do that a while back… unfortunately [it doesn't look like](http://clang-developers.42468.n3.nabble.com/RFC-Starting-support-for-SAL-td3466171.html) other compilers will be supporting SAL any time soon.