# How to deal with C/C++ ambiguity of pointers?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

Let's say that we have a simple function definition...

```
    void fun(type* var);
```

***How should I know what to put in the function....***

- Pass a pointer to a type variable, assuming that function needs
  only pointer to one element...

```
    type ch = ...;
    fun(&ch);
```

- Pass type array, assuming that function needs many types...

```
    type chArr[] = {...};
    fun(chArr);
```

***I know, I know that array holds the address of first element so you can always create for every pointer an type array with one values in, and the code will be the same. But how can I know if its wants 1 or >1 values???***

***It gets worse when we have to pass `char*` because we can't know if the function needs `\0` null terminator to exit operation...***

- Pass a pointer to a char variable, assuming that function needs the only pointer to one char element...

```
    char ch = 'A';
    fun(&ch);
```

- Pass char array, assuming that function needs many char elements with a null pointer at the end...

```
    type chArr[] = "ABC";
    fun(chArr);
```

I know, that you usually know from the documentation what to put into the code but still... How do you know it???

Comment: "*I know that array holds the address of first element*" - more accurately, in certain contexts, passing around an array will *decay* into a pointer to the 1st element.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Read the documentation is already the right way to do it. There are many things you can't tell from just looking at the function signature. So what is your point? And if you are asking about C please don't tag C++. They are different languages.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because [your question is just a rant in disguise: “______ sucks, am I right?”](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: @JaMiT I edit it to not be a rant.

Comment: @UrošJarc Better, but the last line still seems odd for a non-rant: *"I know, that you usually know from the documentation what to put into the code but still... How do you know it???"* The answer to "how do you know it?" is right there in the preceding statement: "you usually know from the documentation". I t might be a good idea to take a break, and re-write this question from scratch after you've let the ranty-ness clear from your thoughts.

Comment: @JaMiT I like a little ranty-ness in my question :)

Comment: A function, or more correctly an interface, is a contract.  It has requirements of both the invocation and implementation.  If you obey your side of the contract, you can rest assured the other side does as well.   If it doesn't?  Unlike a legal contract, you likely can't sue for restitution, but you are unlikely to keep using it, or anything else provided by the vendor.  In this environment, the vendor starves and dies, so the problem disappears, and you are wiser.  Just like a legal contract, an interface can be fraudulent, but what are you to do?  Hide in your basement.  19 characters left.

Comment: This is why tools that scan header files to produce FFI definitions (foreign function interface) can never work 100%. A FFI definition allows some other language, like say Lisp or Python, to call C libraries. You don't know from `fun(char *x)` whether this takes an array or single character. If it takes an array, you don't know whether it must be a null-terminated string. You also don't know whether the function will overwrite the object. You don't know whether you must initialize the object or whether the function will.

Comment: @mevets Yes probably this is what you get if you play on low level programming language...

Comment: Which is what C, by intention is.  Many people, including standards committees want to change it into Pascal, presumably because their feelings were hurt that C succeeded where so many *better* languages languished.  Its expressiveness is due to its embrace of fundamental constructs, not despite them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How should I know what to put in the function....
>
> But how can I know if its wants 1 or >1 values???

From just looking at the function's declaration, you can't determine that (unless the declaration is decorated with [SAL annotations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/sal-annotations), which your example is not).  As you said, the function could want a pointer to a single object, or a pointer to an array of objects.  So, to determine the expected behavior, you will have to look at the function's documentation, or at the function's implementation code if you have access to it.

Comment: Yea you are probably right that from annotations you can assume many things, can you elaborate on that SAL annotation?

Comment: Oh I see this is [a header for only annotations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/sal-annotations?view=msvc-160) COOL, I feel much better now.

Comment: Is there any standard for gcc/clang annotations on linux or some docs for reading the list of all anotations that gcc/clang is using?

Comment: @UrošJarc [Annotating C/C++ code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21398791/)

Comment: We should recommend looking at the documentation first, not the implementation. (And it would be rare to have the implementation and not the documentation, rather than vice-versa.) The documentation is the official expression of what the function should do, not the implementation. The behaviors of the implementation may be a strict superset of the behaviors specified by the documentation, and so a behavior inferred from the implementation may not withstand changes to future versions, ports to other platforms, and other changes of implementation.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should *not* try to decide this based on whether a function parameter is declared as

```
type *arg
```

or

```
type arg[]
```

The `type arg[]` form *suggests* that the pointer might be to an array of several objects.  But many programmers reject this form (precisely because it can be so confusing) and use the `type *arg` form all the time.

As general rules:

1. If it's a `char *` pointer, there's a good chance it points to a null-terminated string.
2. If there's an `int nitems` or `size_t arrsize` argument right next door, the pointer is probably to an array of elements, of the given size.
3. Otherwise, if there's a single pointer argument without a companion 'size' argument, it's probably to a single item.  (Standard examples are `ctime` and `stat`.)

But the documentation for the function should really always say.

Comment: Certainly if there's another argument that conveys an element count then it's usually safe to assume that the function works on possibly many elements of an array.  But it is by no means safe to assume otherwise about functions that don't accept such arguments.  Many string functions serve as ready counterexamples.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Good point, thanks.  Answer updated.

Comment: Yes when there is a similar argument by name and have at the end `count` or `size` word then I can see that its probably array, but usualy I don't have such luxury.

Answer (score 0):

> **How should I know what to put in the function....**
>
> ```
> Pass a pointer to a type variable, assuming that function needs only pointer to one element...
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> ```
> Pass type array, assuming that function needs many types...
> ```

In the first place, there is no essential difference between these from the callee's perspective.  Observe, for instance ...

```
    type chArr[1] = {...};
    fun(chArr);
```

.  That is, a pointer to a scalar can be viewed as a pointer to the first element of a one-element array (explicitly so, according to the language spec).

> **I know, I know that array holds the address of first element so you
> can always create for every pointer an type array with one values in,
> and the code will be the same. But how can I know if its wants 1 or >1
> values???**

How can you know what *any* function does or what it expects of its arguments, whatever their types?  Generally speaking, we rely on documentation, even for functions we have written ourselves.  (You DO document your code clearly and carefully, right?  Future you thanks you for that.)

> **It gets worse when we have to pass char* because we can't know if the function needs \0 null terminator to exit operation...**

No, that's no worse.  You've no particular reason to suppose *a priori* that a function that accepts an array of some other type does not rely on its end to be marked by a sentinel value.

> I know, that you usually know from the documentation what to put into
> the code but still... How do you know it???

You can try to guess from function names, argument names and types, and the function's return type, but that just gives you an hypothesis.  Maybe a pretty good hypothesis, but you don't get any sure information that way.

If you do not have documentation, or it is incomplete, or you don't trust it, then the ultimate recourse is to look at the the code.  Preferably source code, but disassembled object code can work too, if you're desperate.  But if you don't have documentation you can rely on then you should strongly consider the option of *throwing the function away*, or at least avoiding any direct use of it.